# PyQt5, не работает closeEvent()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, closeevent

Прописал метод `closeEvent()`, но он не работает.

Что нужно добавить в код?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Выход', 'Вы точно хотите выйти?',
                                                  QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**НИКОГДА** не изменяйте модуль созданный в `Qt Designer`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Выход', 'Вы точно хотите выйти?',
                                                  QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    Dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_Dialog()
#    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
#    Dialog.show()
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть при создании всех функций программы надо создавать дочерний класс и в нём выполнять все действия?

Comment: @SecorD да, именно так! Относитесь к модулю созданному в Qt Designer.как к ресурсу, ну как к изображению.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что closeEvent не наследуется, так как вы только вызываете функцию.
Наследуйте Ui_Dialog от QDialog, а в **init**() следующее:

```
super().__init__()
self.setupUi(self)
```